# How does one create a struct from a numba struct type?

Tags: python, numba

I can define a numba struct type with:

```
from numba import struct, int32

my_struct_type = struct([('value_a', int32), ('value_b', int32)])
```

Now that I have the type, how do I create an actual struct?

Comment: You submit a documentation bug against `numba` to make them tell you ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`numba.struct` no longer exists, you can now simply pass in standard `numpy` arrays with your custom complicated `dtype`....

```
import numpy as np # version 1.10.1
import numba # version 0.22.1

@numba.jit(nopython=True)
def sum_basic_array(a):
    ret = 0
    for aa in a:
        ret += aa
    return ret

@numba.jit(nopython=True)
def sum_struct_array(a):
    ret = 0
    for aa in a:
        ret += aa.sub_0
    return ret

x_basic = np.arange(20000*3, dtype=np.uint32)
x_struct = x_basic.view(dtype=np.dtype([('sub_0', np.int32),
                                        ('sub_1', np.float64)]))

%timeit sum_basic_array(x_basic) # 18 µs
%timeit sum_struct_array(x_struct) # 8 µs
%timeit sum_struct_array(x_struct.view(np.recarray)) # 40 µs
```

Note that the `sum_struct_array` is doing one third as many iterations, so it shouldn't be a surprise that it's faster.

Answer (score 2):

An example can be found in the [Numba documentation](http://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/0.11/examples.html#Structs)

```
record_type = struct([('x', double), ('y', double)])
record_dtype = record_type.get_dtype()
a = numpy.array([(1.0, 2.0), (3.0, 4.0)], dtype=record_dtype)
```

The struct you create is a numpy [data type object](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/arrays.dtypes.html), not an actual new type in Python

For your code example this would be:

```
my_struct_type = struct([('value_a', int32), ('value_b', int32)])
my_struct = np.array([(1, 2)], dtype=my_struct_type)
```